# how can I get the logit values as probabilities from gpt-2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tensor

I'm using the gpt-2 simple package: https://github.com/minimaxir/gpt-2-simple

I would like to get a probability for all possible next tokens as an output. something like:

[ ['A', 0.25], ['B',0.25], ['C',0.25], ['D',0.25] ]

I've modified the gpt_2_simple python code looks something like this:

```
full_output = sample.sample_sequence(
    hparams=hparams,
    length=min(length, 1023 - (len(context_tokens) if prefix else 0)),
    start_token=enc.encoder['<|endoftext|>'] if not prefix else None,
    context=context if prefix else None,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    temperature=temperature, top_k=top_k, top_p=top_p
)

logit_output = full_output[:,0:]

out = sess.run(output, feed_dict={context: batch_size * [context_tokens]})

logit_out = sess.run(logit_output, feed_dict={context: batch_size * [context_tokens]})
```

I was hoping to link the output tokens to their temperature divided logit values and then decode them, to get probabilities for each token like the example above.

Can anyone help me to reformat this code so that I can access the output token / logit probability combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) get list of decoded tokens:

```
enc = gpt_2_simple.src.encoder.get_encoder(checkpoint_path)
N_token = len(enc.encoder)
tokens_decoded = [enc.decode([token]) for token in range(N_token)]
```

2) get probabilities:

```
probs = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```